# How can I fix the 404 error and display my image on Github gh-pages?

Tags: image, path, http-status-code-404, github-pages, failed-to-load-viewstate

Cant see the image in Github gh-pages but no problem in local.

the error i get is 404
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMtGV.png)

https://erdal-u.github.io/mywebsite/
https://github.com/erdal-u

i have tried with small and big letters and all the ./images/img.jpg possibilities i think

i try see my image but it not show in gh-pages.
i try to fix the path in every way and change all letters to small.